# Range of $cos\ \frac{a-c}{2}$ in a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

My doubt is from a question and I will extract my query and relevant information.

> How to find the range of $cos\ \frac{a-c}{2}$ if a,b,c are angles of a triangle and b=120°(Don't think this is needed)

The maximum value should be 1 when a,c are equal in value but it's the minimum I am not able to find.

A point in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Hint : What's the range of $a-c$ ?

Comment: @cosmo5 Got it ! Thanks please copy paste as an answer I will accept it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

For $b = 120^{\circ}$, $$|a-c| \in [0,60^{\circ})$$

$$\Rightarrow \cos \frac{a-c}{2} \in (\cos 30^{\circ},1]$$